# Open an imported PDF from deployed app

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, pdf

I wanted to open a PDF when clicking on a button. It worked, when I used the file on my desktop. Then I imported the PDF into the project, because the PDF should open on every computer and not only on mine.

I tried to adress the path there and it doesn't work.

```
else if(arg0.getSource() == this.rules) {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.pdf");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check your input file!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the file path is right? Its an absolute path (begins with /) but looks that it should be a relative one

Comment: Well I looked at the pdf in the project and copied the path on properties. It should be right I guess. It always prints out "Check your input file"

Comment: An absolute paths referes to your computers file system as a whole, not just to your project.

Assumint "path" is a folder directly under resources. "to" a folder under "path" and file.pdf is in "to", please try with new File("path/to/file.pdf")

Comment: Oh thank you. It works now... What a dumb mistake by me

Comment: *"Then I imported the PDF into the project, because the PDF should open on every computer and not only on mine."* The PDF will end up inside the Jar file, so won't be accessible as a `File` on the user's computer. There are various approaches to fixing that, depending on the level of trade off between ease for the user and programming for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding the comment as an answer so the question's does not remain as unaswered

An absolute paths referes to your computers file system as a whole, not just to your project.

Assumint "path" is a folder directly under resources, "to" a folder under "path" and file.pdf is in "to", please try with:

```
 new File("path/to/file.pdf")
```